# Intellij macro deleted on restart

Tags: macros, intellij-idea

I've recently started using IntellIJ macros. The problem is that they get deleted whenever I restart my system / intellij (not sure).

Is there a way I may prevent it from getting deleted and having to record it again on a restart?

Answer (score 1):

Macros are stored in [`%CONFIG%`](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181)`\options\macros.xml` file. Verify that this file exists and is not removed or overwritten between the restarts.

Comment: Thanks for coming to the rescue :)
Sorry but I can't seem to find the config folder anywhere. Where is it supposed to be?